# How to generate only one editor for more models in EMF?

Tags: eclipse, model, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have more EMF genmodels. It is pretty lame to create new editor for each model. After generation (right click - generateAll) old editor is always overridden.

Comment: Do you mean that you have several ecore models that you wish to generate only one editor for?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is that EMF does not support this.

You could try asking on the EMF mailing lists.  But if you do, you need to be a bit more tactful.  If you start by suggesting that their code is "lame" most developers tend to switch out of "being helpful to newbies" mode.